# Why there's only 3 items in the Community Bulletin?

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-bulletin

According to the rules of how are post show in the CB:

> - If there are still under 4 items, the rest of the space is filled with **[hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions** not marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), scoring at least 3 and posted within the past two weeks. These are picked semi-randomly. At least *one* of these will always be added to the list, even if it pushes the length over 4.

Yet, the only items are the 3 [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) questions, but there's enough [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)'s questions that fulfill the criteria, and the CB don't use the fourth slot. FIX PLOX?

Comment: I see 3 featured meta questions also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Logical error wasn't choosing meta posts to fill the bulletin up to 4 (or more) properly.

This was fixed in the latest deploy.