# Shouldn't we have at least one hot meta posts network wide on the community bulletin?

Tags: bug, community-bulletin

#### This is not a duplicate of [What happened to the Hot Meta Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312035/what-happened-to-the-hot-meta-posts), they are different issues, as this is not only network wide (other issue was specific to SO), but it is easily reproducible (for moderators), unlike the randomness the other issue presents (as a workaround developers [refresh the cache](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=4319645#4319645) which wouldn't have any effect here).

According to [What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621/213575)

> - If there are still under 4 items, the rest of the space is filled with **[hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions** not marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), scoring at least 3 and posted within the past two weeks. These are picked semi-randomly. **At least *one* of these will always be added to the list, even if it pushes the length over 4.** (Note that the timing and tags [can be adjusted per-site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268576/why-do-feature-requests-and-support-questions-appear-in-the-community-bulletin/268577#268577) to suit the needs of each community)

I see two blog posts and two featured posts (2+2=4, right?), but no hot meta posts. Is this intended?

Current community bulletin:

> [image: SO community bulletin]

This is network wide, since [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) have the same issue:

> [image: Unix community bulletin]

They have [hot meta posts](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot), but they don't appear on the community bulletin at all. Though [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) seems to not have this problem.

The other post is about the random disappearance of hot meta posts.  In *this* case, the community bulletin isn't respecting the intended behavior of having at least 1 hot meta post even if it pushes the length of the bulletin over 4 items.

Comment: possibly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312035/what-happened-to-the-hot-meta-posts

Comment: because meta is cool?

Comment: meta is murder @gnat, remember!

Comment: I've actually been seeing this for months, and just never really bothered to make a post about it. Every time it's gotten to two blogs and two featured, or a blog and three featured, the hot posts list has disappeared for me.

Comment: @Kendra This isn't the first time it happens, when there are [many featured/blog posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270113/792066), but before was that it didn't filled the 4 slots.

Comment: @Kendra why the duplicate close votes? This is another issue altogether.

Comment: @Braiam Yeah, I just realized he's the one who posted the related link, and with the first two letters being the same... No big deal! :)

Comment: Also, after refreshing, I see a different bulletin now.  It has 1 event, 2 blogs, 1 featured post, 0 hot questions.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Samthebrand just took featured off the survey question, and I'm assuming they made it an event to replace that.

Comment: @Kendra makes sense.  But interesting that it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Braiam i didn't vote, just noted that it might be related.

Comment: @KevinB well, guess what you caused?

Comment: This doesn't affect all sites network wide, Server Fault and UX Stack Exchange still have Hot Meta Posts. But they also don't have featured meta posts, so maybe that is related.

Comment: @KevinBrown exactly, the issue only appears when featured posts fill up all the 4 slots.

Comment: Don't worry, once this post shows up in the hot network list, they won't be able to ignore it! ... Wait a second

Comment: [Current bulletin](http://i.imgur.com/H93qc2U.png) is even more extreme.  5 pinned things but 0 hot posts.

Comment: [Fixed now](http://i.imgur.com/6mOxWql.png)?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Not for me: http://i.imgur.com/ZdQT22V.jpg

Comment: @NathanOliver but that did show a "Hot meta post" just not the featured on meta.  Also my picture is from the main SO not MSO.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Oops.  looking at the wrong thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code around community bulletin is ...historical and needs some rewrite love. In fact the logic is quite convoluted and hard to explain.

There was code to limit the items displayed in two different places. This could be at best neutral and at worst could be the cause of this bug.

I am pushing a fix, let's take it from there.

Comment: Can we feature 4 posts now? You know, for science

Comment: Mind taking another look at this? It appears to be happening again.

Comment: @Sklivvz Doesn't seem like this problem was fixed. Do to the many current featured events and questions, there hasn't been a hot meta post section showing for quite some time now.

Comment: It happened again http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343224/792066