# No hot meta post, again

Tags: bug, community-bulletin

This kinda happens whenever there's many featured items and at least one blog item as seen [Minimum number of hot meta posts not shown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336870/792066) and [Shouldn't we have at least one hot meta posts network wide on the community bulletin?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314207/792066) The code needs serious love.