# What happened to Hot Meta Posts again?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, hot-questions, community-bulletin

For at least three days now, there are no Hot Meta Posts in the bulletin. It currently has 3 links only (two blog posts and a "Featured on Meta" post):

[image: bulletin]

**Similar posts that don't answer this question:**

- [What happened to the Hot Meta Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312035/what-happened-to-the-hot-meta-posts)
- [No hot meta post, again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343224/no-hot-meta-post-again)
- [Minimum number of hot meta posts not shown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336870/minimum-number-of-hot-meta-posts-not-shown)

Also, let me quote from this [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/348196):

> If there are still under four items, the rest of the space is filled with **hot [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) questions** not marked with any moderator status tag, scoring at least 3 and posted within the past two weeks.
>
> ...
>
> If there are any featured or hot meta posts, at least two will always be added to the list, even if it pushes the length over 4.

**Is this a bug or are there some recent changes to the bulletin?**

Comment: Works for me, from a tab loaded a few hours ago before the question there got `status-completed`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxobF.png

Comment: @CertainPerformance Are you sure it's not cached? Before posting, I tested on a Chrome _guest_ session (no extensions, scripts, etc.) and still didn't see any HMPs.

Comment: It is cached for a bit, but that question there may well have been pushed out of it in the last couple hours due to the `status-completed`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't there be more than just one post (at least two?) given that there are currently other Hot Meta Posts? [Here's one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/404302/revisions), for example.

Comment: me to also have the same problem

Comment: I had Hot Meta Posts a few hours ago, but I just noticed they were missing and came here to find out what was going on... good to know it's not just me...

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure why they seem to come and go for some users. I haven't seen a single one for 3 days!

Comment: @41686d6564 strange, I've had them all day today, but took a break for a few hours and they were gone when I came back.

Comment: Based on my observation, looks like the rule is [mixed with the HNQ rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/241919): Closed (dupe) questions cannot become hot. Questions cannot become hot multiple times. Questions can only become hot at most for 3 days. Status-tagged questions are also not valid (only valid for meta). The rest of the eligible [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bdiscussion%5d%20score%3a3%20closed%3a0%20-%5bstatus*%5d)s have become hot once or too old.

Comment: I guess "hot" doesn't mean "hottest".

Comment: Easy test: Make this a [discussion] question and see whether it pops up? ;)

Comment: Ironically, Hot Meta Posts appears to be back now and this is the only post on it.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I suspect that's because I added [discussion]

Comment: It is indeed [an amusing sight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPtBu.png).

Comment: I can currently only see "Swag is coming back", no HMPs from SO.

Comment: @Trilarion same. I did see [this question earlier today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404392) even though it was already closed at the time. It was probably caching in its case but it does mean it qualified for the HMP and was on it. So...is it as simple as "there are no qualifying questions"? It has to be tagged `[discussion]` (not `[support]` or `[bug]`) with a score of 3 or higher, as far as I know.

Comment: According to this all posts should be considered for the bulletin board https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252467/792066

Comment: I didn't see a hot meta post listed there for days, but today there happens to be one. Seems to be working, there just isn't so much hotness right now.