# Post notice shows who voted to close a question... unless it was my question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions, post-notice

Because I have the [**cast close and reopen votes** privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), I can see who voted to close any question on the post notice. Well, I just had [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404382/8967612) of mine closed (I even was one of the close-voters) and it surprised me to see that the post notice doesn't show the voters as usual:

[image: Post notice]

I'm starting to doubt my memory but I'm 99.99% sure that this was never the case, even after the [new post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/348196) introduced a while ago. So, this appears to be caused by a recent change.

**Notes:**

- I posted here instead of on Meta.SE because I couldn't tell if this is the case across the network (since I only have the said privilege on Stack Overflow).
- I'm also not sure if this is the case on the main site or if it's just on meta.
- I know I can see the missing information in the Timeline but that's not the point.

Comment: This is as SE intends it to be. You can find the users who voted to close from either the question's history page or its timeline. There's a Meta post, IIRC on MSE, which describes this as intended, but I don't have a link handy at the moment.

Comment: @Makyen I would appreciate it if you can refer me to it whenever you have the time. As I said above, I'm 99% sure that I've seen the post notice showing close voters on my own questions before (after the new post notices).

Comment: Yeah, it was one of the updates to the post notices after the main switch to the current format. So, yes, it's quite possible that you did see the new post notice format showing the close voters on your own questions. If it's any consolation, the close voters are even hidden from moderators on our own questions. :;

Comment: Nope; your memory is faulty. This was definitely a part of the updates to the post notices. It's the case network-wide, including on Meta sites. And, yes, you can see the information in the Timeline view still. This is not intended to hide information from experienced users, but only to prevent new users unfamiliar with how our curation system works from blaming individuals. Too often, instead of focusing on the *reason* for closure, new users were focusing on the *people* involved. This has been an overwhelmingly positive change.

Comment: (Although, personally, I'd always show the list of close-voters to anyone who themselves has close-vote privileges on a site, which would include you, here. Such users understand how the closure system works, and thus hiding the information from them serves no purpose. However, that is not the way the team implemented it, and I'd much rather have this, what I consider to be an "imperfect" implementation, over what we had before, which was shoving these names in everyone's faces.)

Comment: @Cody Yes, I agree that this is better than showing the names to everyone. And I'm aware that the updates to post notices a year ago hid the names from users who don't have the privilege. I was just under the impression that 3K+ users can still see the votes even on their own questions. I even (think I) remember seeing them a couple of times on my closed questions. But perhaps my memory is faulty as you suggested. Two mods have confirmed this after all, and you're obviously more experienced with the system than I am :)

Comment: You may be remembering the way I *wanted* the revamped system to work, rather than the way it actually does. :-)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332502/165773

Comment: @gnat [status-completed] in last July. So, I was (partially?) right. Phew! I'm glad I'm not losing my memory.

Comment: Yes, the new post notices [rolled out on SO on 2019-10-29](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow), and [went live network-wide on 2019-12-05](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide). The answer @gnat linked indicates the usernames were [removed from the post notices shown to authors by 2020-07-20](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/332502/6). So, the close-voters were visible to question authors in the new post notices for 9 months on SO and 7 1/2 months on all other sites.

Comment: The surprising part is that other people are shown that the normal message is "(Viewable **by the post author** and users with the close/reopen votes privilege)".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think that that part refers to the details of the close reason (which really should be visible to _**all**_ users). I actually have a [feature request on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356902/348196) about this.

Comment: @41686d6564 Since it comes after the reason and the list of close voters, at least to me the message implies *both* should be viewable by the post author. Either way, I agree the reason should be visible to all.