# Feature non-[discussion] meta post in the community bulletin

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-bulletin

According to [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252467/792066):

> So, **for Meta Stack Overflow only, we'll now be featuring all hot meta questions scoring 3 or more in the bulletin**. And we'll exclude those more than 3 days old, to keep it fresh. As before, the list will be chosen randomly every 20 minutes or thereabouts from the pool of eligible questions.

It seems that the later part (only post less than 3 days old) is being applied to Meta Stack Overflow, while the former (all post should be eligible) is being ignored. This change came about [with the Community Bulletin being reinstated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400216/). Now, I don't see the reason why other tags shouldn't be featured at all, specially if we still have the younger than 3 days restriction (it's my not-so-scientific observation that the randomness was also lost).

The feature request is linked to note that [hot questions may have tweaks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/213575) per-site, but [it seems that the tweaks were partly removed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404382/792066).

I'm tagging this [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) with the double purpose of having a discussion about if we still expect all post to be eligible, and also to make sure that this post isn't adversely affected by the potential bug.

Comment: [It's a change when the feature was reactivated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400216/). I can't explain the rationale behind it.

Comment: @VLAZ The post you linked says "*What we really want to avoid in the Hot Meta Posts are questions that call out, or are rude towards, specific users, moderators, or staff.*" which specifically targets [support] questions and (to a lesser extent) [feature-request]s.

Comment: If a question becomes a "hot meta post" and is a "rude towards, specific users, moderators, or staff" I have concerns; why is a post that is rude towards anyone getting enough upvotes to be "hot"? Surely the voters should *not* be up voting rude questions, and *hopefully* enough respectful users will have flagged the question as such and it is closed/deleted.

Comment: @Larnu The community and the staff have had different views on what constitutes 'rude'.

Comment: Even different users can have varying opinions of what is "rude", @TylerH , but that doesn't really change my point there, if I am honest. I would expect that the community is more likely to find more things rude that SE are. I would suggest it would be "easy" to ensure that if a post has a "rude or abusive" flag on it, it would not be displayed as "hot" until a mod clears it (which would permit the post being "hot" there onwards).

Comment: We should be more generous with the discussion tag, especially for upvoted content.

Comment: I see two potential solutions: either we get the same treatment as other sites where hot has a limit of two weeks, or any tag becomes eligible.

Comment: I would think that a [discussion] is more likely to be "rude" than either [support] or [feature-request]. So, this prohibition is quite odd to me, even putting aside the fact that opinions differ on what might be "rude".

Comment: [Rudeness is in the eye of the beholder.](https://i.imgur.com/pFczkVt.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We discussed this internally and we've made the following changes based on my review of the linked posts.

We're going to reset SO (and the rest of the network, in fact) to the actual default for tagged questions - which is to include questions tagged with either [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) in the bulletin.   We think that feature requests, in particular are often places where having more community involvement is really beneficial, which is why this has been added network-wide.

Why are we continuing to exclude bug and support questions? Because, in general, these are questions that are more likely to need the attention of staff (in the case of bugs) or people who are highly fluent in SO's systems or culture (support). Since we've added visibility through the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag for bugs and support questions that need a staff response, I'm not sure about the value in presenting these to the wider community.

If there's a bug that's very problematic and mods want users to be aware of it for a period when it's not fixed, then the better solution to me would be to feature it so that it's locked into being visible rather than relying on the fates to choose it to appear in the bulletin. For support questions, the same could be done or one could consider whether the question is one asking for support or really looking for a discussion - as Shog hinted at, questions about merging or blocking tags are more of a *discussion* rather than a support request.

I hope that this addresses your concerns and brings more discussions and features to the eyes of the broader SO community.

Comment: Any chances of having the aggressive rotation of post back? One of the reasons why SO got everything in there was because shorter window of opportunity and randomness in the posts, rather than just the top voted ones.

Comment: If you read the comments on Shog's answer, it says that it wasn't actually 20 minutes, it was an hour, unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: It can be still one hour, but since only the top voted post will be promoted, it becomes a feedback loop. With the rotation (random from the top 20 eligible or something) there's chances of being fresh. That's what my comment is about.

Comment: Why do you think only the top voted post is promoted? The HMP picks randomly everywhere, not only on SO. That's in the quote in Shog's answer - it says that they're random.

Comment: Really? Observations don't agree. I've seen the same questions for days usually.

Comment: If there's a bug, that *should* be unrelated to this and would likely be network-wide and would require more investigation. As far as I'm aware HMPs should always be random. SO rarely has space for them, though. Feel free to post a bug report about it - and if it does look like it's network-wide, maybe put it on MSE... but your question here is focused on the tags, which is what we fixed. I don't have the ability to just dig through the code and see if it's still working.

Comment: Adam says the code that's supposed to make it random is definitely still there but it seems that we've stopped serving HMPs network-wide, so we can't even confirm that the random selection is working correctly until we get them showing up again. :)

Comment: Only [discussion] tagged questions aren't being displayed. [feature requests] are. Should I open a bug report for that?

Comment: @Braiam It's [reported on Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33411/536049), and per a recent chat discussion in the Meta.SE Tavern, the team is aware of it.