# Minimum number of hot meta posts not shown

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-bulletin

I don't hang out on [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions), but I often read meta questions that are displayed on the Hot Meta Posts panel. I also like to read the Blog and Featured on Meta posts that show up on the same panel.

According to [How are the contents of the Community Bulletin determined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621/213575)

> - If there are still under 4 items, the rest of the space is filled with **[hot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogNNBm.png) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions** not marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), scoring at least 3 and posted within the past two weeks. These are picked semi-randomly. **At least *one* of these will always be added to the list, even if it pushes the length over 4.** (Note that the timing and tags [can be adjusted per-site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268576/why-do-feature-requests-and-support-questions-appear-in-the-community-bulletin/268577#268577) to suit the needs of each community)

This doesn't appear to be happening for some reason:

[image]

Can this please be fixed?

Still a problem with 1 event and 3 featured:

[image]

Observations:

- 2017-02
- 2017-07-12
- 2017-08-30
- 2017-09-19
- 2017-10-17 2 blog + 1 mse featured + 2 mso featured
- 2017-11-16

Comment: Every meta post is interesting :D

Comment: This is a bug; not sure how you want to write it but I briefly edited to outline the bug.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314207/shouldnt-we-have-at-least-one-hot-meta-posts-network-wide-on-the-community-bull?s=2|1.0190, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270000/why-theres-only-3-items-in-the-community-bulletin?s=2|1.1547 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332209/after-removing-the-featured-tag-featured-items-arent-unfeatured-that-or-they?s=3|0.6086

Comment: Would be nice to point out which questions you feel should not be on there or which you feel should be on there but aren't, rather than making employees (or others) go through each of those links...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it lacks at least **one** hot meta post.

Comment: @Braiam Oh, so the problem is a lack of a hot meta post? There should be a free-hand circle around the blank spot under the last post in the screenshot. That's the only possible way it would be clear. ;)

Comment: @Braiam what's the problem? I would expect the list to be filled up to four items, which it is: two blogs, two featured questions.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think I answered that question just two comments above.

Comment: @Braiam well yeah if you thought writing was hard, reading can be even harder. So the bullet point should start with _"There will always be one hot discussion question in the list, and more as long as the total number of items in the list is less than four"_ or something like that.

Comment: @CodeCaster well, it's Shog masterpiece. You really want to critique?

Comment: I like seeing the hot meta posts as well, and agree the code should be changed to always show at least one hot meta post. Over the last few months, between documentation sunsetting, the new top bar design and the plethora of blog posts, there has almost never been room for any hot meta posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior I described there was added on May 23rd, 2012, and I updated the answer to reflect it the same day. However... Either I misunderstood the update as it was relayed to me, or I was given incorrect information, as the behavior *never* matched the description I wrote.

The *actual* logic in place for the past 4.5 years is as described in the revised answer:

> If there are any featured or hot meta posts, at least 1 will always be added to the list, even if it pushes the length over 4.

Comment: Any chances to improve this behaviour? At least one or two hot meta posts would be very nice :)

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but [sometimes it might be okay to have none.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358542/question-feed-icon-circle-looks-like-a-potato)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt seems to be like a FR, but I would wait until some posts get de-featured for more exposure ;)

Comment: "as the behavior never matched the description I wrote", I recall that there was a time where we got 1 hot meta post with 5 items.

Comment: That could happen if 4 were some combination of events (election for instance), blog posts, and network-wide featured posts, @braiam

Comment: My original question was a feature request, not a bug report. It was subsequently edited by someone else into a bug report. I'm accepting this answer to my question in its current form. However, like @ChristianGollhardt, I would also like to see at least one or two hot meta posts at all times. I get bored of seeing the features posts and blogs when they are taking up all the space for a week.

Comment: There are a couple of things we could do there, @Suragch; the most obvious one would be to not have lots and lots of featured posts - we should be doing that already, but sometimes there are a combination of factors that make it unlikely. The other option is to increase the total number of slots in the bulletin - if this continues to be common, that might be the best option.

Comment: I like the second option. I'm not sure if it is bad from a UI perspective, but I certainly wouldn't mind having the bulletin be longer.

Comment: [Done](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359485/dynamicly-expand-the-community-bullentin-if-no-hot-meta-post-is-shown) @Braiam