# Question Feed Icon - Circle looks like a potato

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, rss

When zooming on the SVG icon of Question Feed:

[image: Question Feed]

...it looks like this:

[image: Question Feed icon]

## This is *horrible*.

It's obviously a PNG/JPG image that got vectorized by Vector Magic or something like that. I draw a better icon in Sketch in 5 minutes.

I'd suggest changing it.

Note that this only affects the image on Stack Overflow, since this is part of the per-site SVG sprite sheet. It looks like a perfectly-round circle here on Meta.

Comment: Didn't you know that potatoes are the "new thang" in UI design? :)

Comment: I zoomed in on your avatar and it's even worse. [Just look!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: Now that you mention it, I think the arcs look like macaronis. But it is an icon for a feed, so maybe an image composed of different foods is [meta-tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: You can see that the dot is not round even in the normal size version.

Comment: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg Also note: the logo at the top and bottom have different curves defining the layout of the orange rectangles.  I recall reading about the evolution from [the logo contest winner](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/04/30/logo-design-contest-winner/) to [the current logo](https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos), but I couldn't find the article just now. IIRC the article directly addressed the layout of the rectangles and the removal of the color fade.

Comment: @the4kman, This is not _horrible_, it is only _stupid_ (to convert from bitmap to vector image for something that is very shape-based).  For perspective, remember that this potato doesn't keep people from being able to use the site. Crashing servers would be _horrible_.

Comment: The feed must have gotten too long, so they decided to console you with [a potato](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzkKD.jpg).

Comment: @NH. I  strongly believe OP was sarcastic.

Comment: enhance...  enhance... enhance... yup that's a potato

Comment: You are assuming this icon is for a RSS feed. It could also be for buying [potato feed](https://www.marshalls-seeds.co.uk/concentrated-potato-feed-pre-planting-pid5042.html)!

Comment: "I draw a better icon in Sketch in 5 minutes." Go on then, you know you want to :)

Comment: You say potahto..

Comment: It's just a freehand circle; I don't know what the problem is. Should have been red though.

Comment: If you scroll in enough to see that, the sites layout is completely broken. I wonder if they have never heard of responsive design at SO.

Comment: I can't find it within myself to downvote this, because, trivial as it is, it is still a legitimate issue. I do wish there was some sort of automatic punishment that could be handed out to anyone commenting on it, though. Present commenter included, of course, I'm a firm proponent of justice.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I feel the same way. And I feel sad that I actually read the post. I know I have more of a life than this...

Comment: Maybe it has taken hours to design the icon with carefully planned square, which looks like a pentagon. How would the creator feel when seeing this post ..?

Comment: I do not know where you found that horribly drawn feed logo. But everywhere i looked i could not find it its perfectly round for me

Comment: @Tomm daveloyall already linked the per-site SVG sheet for SO, it's present there (https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg).

Comment: Note that [serverfault's](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/serverfault/img/sprites.svg) and [superuser's](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/superuser/img/sprites.svg) RSS feed icons are circular!

Comment: I don't even know where is Question Feed located.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. It is very likely we broke this icon doing some sort of SVG optimization... Also, we're trying to **not** use sprites anymore (if possible) so from now on this icon will be standalone SVG, unified across SE network.

Consider this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) – fix is waiting in repo for next build.