# Double quotes appears above advertisement

Tags: bug, advertising

The image should explain the bug:

[image: Screenshot of the top of a Microsoft Azure ad. A quotation mark appears above the ad at its left edge and inline with its info and close buttons. The quotation mark has a freehand red circle around it and a freehand red arrow pointing to the circle.]

Comment: ["Microsoft"](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/594/192/596.gif)

Comment: Trust ad-providers to screw up their JS code...

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I didn't want innocent people to think that the circle is part of the bug.

Comment: @Maroun Those same people will think both the circle and arrow are part of the bug.

Comment: It is [working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwaUG.png) for me. Chrome (latest), Windows, ad is in portuguese.

Comment: This bug should be related with those icons [to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ7qO.png) (green circle). I don't know why they are displayed for you, the icons don't appear for me.

Comment: @Zanon normally you should have those buttons, they are for report the advert and "close" it.

Comment: Maybe you need to hover over the ad to see the bug, so it looks like [meta-tag:status-norepro] to me.

Comment: @Zanon You do have the same kind of circle and arrow though, so maybe it is part of the bug after all…?

Comment: You just wish it was [a potato](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358542/1739000), that's all...

Comment: @NH. I'm now scared to zoom in the quotes.

Answer (score 4):

I work on the Ops team at SO. This looks like a copy/paste issue during implementation. @Maroun can you let us know where you're located? This will help us narrow down the ad causing the issue.

Comment: Sure, Tel Aviv. Adds appears in Hebrew.

Comment: Thanks! We'll investigate and update the ad.

Comment: ["Investigate"](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/594/192/596.gif). Sorry.. I had to.

Comment: Does sending an email count as an investigation? Ha.

Comment: I saw the exact same ad with the bug in Hamburg, Germany.

Comment: Same here Bavaria, Germany [-> Image of the full page <-](https://www2.pic-upload.de/img/34641663/bug.png)

Comment: May it got something to do with the azure advertisement.

Comment: @Denimjean yeah its the first part, your advert is bugging can you fix, then they go no it's your implementation or yeah sorry our bad, always delegate investigation under your control :P

Answer (score 3):

I’ve also encountered the same issue in NRW, Germany. If it helps, here is some insight on the generated ad code. As it turns out, there is not actually just a single quotation mark, but there are two that are surrounding the `dcmads` element:

```
<div class="GoogleActiveViewClass" id="DfaVisibilityIdentifier_502645432">
    <div id="ad_unit">
        <!-- scripts and styles -->
        <div id="abgc" class="abgc" dir="ltr" aria-hidden="true">…</div>
        <div id="cbb" class="cbb" aria-hidden="true">…</div>
        <div id="mute_panel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <div id="abgac" class="abgac" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <!-- more scripts -->
    </div>
    "
    <ins class="dcmads"
         data-dcm-placement="N572608.3087890DBM_AMNET0/B20601855.211740207"
         data-dcm-rendering-mode="script" data-dcm-https-only=""
         data-dcm-click-tracker="[UNENCODED_CLICK_REDIRECT]"
         data-dcm-resettable-device-id=""
         data-dcm-app-id=""
         data-dcm-processed="y">
        …
    </ins>
    "
</div>
```

As you can see, there are quotes around the `<ins>` element.

Comment: (This makes [CodeCaster’s comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361792/double-quotes-appears-above-advertisement/361855#comment547243_361792) even more appropriate…)