# Dynamically Expand the Community Bulletin, if no Hot Meta Post is shown

Tags: feature-request, community-bulletin

We have the Hot Meta posts, which are IMHO extremely useful:

[image: Hot Meta Posts]

But sometimes, if we have many [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) or Blog Posts or whatever, they are hidden. We also have had a [Bug Report about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336870/minimum-number-of-hot-meta-posts-not-shown).

It turned out, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). ([Reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359453/2441442))

[Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336870/minimum-number-of-hot-meta-posts-not-shown#comment532781_359453) also commented on his answer about the bug:

> The other option is to increase the total number of slots in the
>   bulletin - if this continues to be common, that might be the best
>   option.

So yes, that would be the behavior I expect.

Can we please dynamically expand the *Community Bulletin* (the 'Featured On Meta' section), if otherwise no *Hot Meta Post* would be shown?

Comment: Now I know why I wasn't seeing them the past week or so. I think this suggestion is extremely usefull. We might also consider to limit the amount of blogposts shown to 1, and to give a maximum length something can be featured. I think that question about a template for new users was around way too long.

Comment: @Luuklag If only those blog posts [would automatically get unpinned to prevent this abuse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276671/keep-pinned-messages-pinned-without-14-days-limit-in-chat-rooms)

Comment: Interestingly, I'm now seeing zero "Featured On Meta" questions

Comment: NVM, now they're back

Comment: They probably don't want the bulletin to push the ads in the sidebar out of sight. Still, I don't think it would be unreasonable to show, instead of four items altogether, *at least* one post per category. Additionally, the headers ("Featured on Meta", "Hot Meta Posts", etc.) could link to meta with an equivalent sort filter pre-applied. Or keep the bulletin as-is with a "show more" link or something. My $0.02 ideas anyway.

Comment: Pre-emptive question: how many hot meta posts do you want to be added?