# Differences about Hot Meta Posts right side bar

Tags: discussion

I have noticed about Hot Meta Posts ordering. The ordering of posts are different on Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow Meta.

I have reload the page few times at both the places and it's not random order. It's displaying as per ascending upvote score on Stack Overflow and no ordering on Stack Overflow Meta.

Is it random order or sort ascending as per upvote or a bug?

Stack Overflow Meta:

[image: Stackoverflow Meta]

Stack Overflow:

[image: Stackoverflow]

Comment: No, it is random. And it is cached.

Comment: It's not a random and I have cleared a cache and login back again and still seeing the same. and in addition, Reproduced in Opera 54.0.2952.71 and have not checked other browser and not sure about same issue with others.

Comment: It is not your cache ...

Comment: @Nisarg: Cached on the *server*, not by your browser. That is, everyone sees the same set of questions, until the server picks a new set at random.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336870/minimum-number-of-hot-meta-posts-not-shown/359453#359453 and the answer to your question is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/158100) if you take the server side caching into account as well.